# Download hardware profile for Xiaomi MI 9T

Tags: android, android-studio, xiaomi, android-device-manager

is there a repository where it is possible to download hardware profile for xiaomi MI 9T, in order to import in android studio device manager?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you try this  
https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-xiaomi